# I want PayU payment module code for magento without redirect to PayU website

Tags: magento, payu

Is it possible to process all payment authentication and authorization for on my site without redirection on Pay U site in `magento`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?